# OnClick on table row - Except on Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which I have the following event:

```
$("#tp-active-list-table td").click(function () {
    var transactionNbr = parseInt($(this).parent("tr").children('td.td-transaction-nbr').html());
    DoSomething(transactionNbr);
});
```

It works fine and basically it calls the `DoSomething` with the `Number` gathered from the respective `td`.

But I do have a problem, since in one of the `td`s I have an anchor, and if the click is performed on that anchor, then the `DoSomething` will run, and the page will correctly navigate to another URL.

Is there anyway to check if the click was on that `anchor` to avoid running the `DoSomething` function?

Comment: If you want the link to be followed why does anything need to be done?

Comment: @j08691 I don't want anything to be done. That's the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent bubbling of events.

```
$('td a').click(function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Other option would be : `e.target.tagName`

```
$("#tp-active-list-table td").click(function (e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'){
            var transactionNbr = parseInt($(this).parent("tr").children('td.td-transaction-nbr').html());
            DoSomething(transactionNbr);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, I was just going to write this

Comment: This imply binding a new event, which is not the best IMO.

Comment: +1 also... Beat me too

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon is right here. It is just a workaround. But effective.

Comment: `e.target.tagName` is dangerous if there the `a` has children. Since jQuery is used, if you take a look at the question I linked as duplicated, I use `.closest()` on the target, which is IMO the best solutions.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, that solution with `.closest()` seems the best.

Answer (score 1):

the object that is passed to your handler function as the first argument has property `target` if `target.tagName == 'a'` then you clicked on an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I think Shaunak's answer very effective. Just to point out another approach, on the click event you can check if there's an hovered `a` tag. http://jsfiddle.net/Zx7S5/

```
$("#tp-active-list-table td").click(function(event) {
    if($(this).find("a:hover").length <= 0) {

       /* ..... */

    }
});
```